# Add class or ID to any Wordpress function

Tags: functions, templates, css

I often find the need to add class or ID's to Wordpress functions. Preferably I would like to do this in the a template (not in `functions.php`).

Example:
`<?php the_excerpt(); ?>` Will output the excerpt inside `<p>`. How can I add a class to the paragraph so that I get `<p class="something">The excerpt text...</p>`

Comment: WP does not provide filters for this. Your option would be to create your own excerpt function or use $post->post_excerpt instead of the_excerpt() this way you have control on the wrapper and its classes.

Comment: How do I use `$post->post_excerpt`? Can you please provide an example?

Comment: e.g. `echo '<p>' . $post->post_content . '</p>';` in your template instead of `the_excerpt() ;`  however this will return empty value if the post does not have a set excerpt.

Comment: Thanks. `<?php $the_excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); if ( '' != $the_excerpt ) {} echo $the_excerpt; ?>` seemed to do the trick for me. I'll just wrap it in a `<p>`

Comment: If you found a solution please remember to post it as an answer to your own question and accept it . thanks

Comment: [`get_the_excerpt`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_excerpt/)

Comment: Yeah, I read that. Not sure what you are trying to say here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one template it's fine to do something like:

```
echo '<p class="whatever">' . get_the_excerpt() . '</p>';
```

However, if you have multiple templates and want to control the classes centrally, you can make a filter on [`get_the_excerpt`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_the_excerpt/) as follows (but yeah, that would be in `functions.php`):

```
add_filter ('get_the_excerpt','wpse240352_filter_excerpt');

function wpse240352_filter_excerpt ($post_excerpt) { 
  $post_excerpt = '<p class="whatever">' . $post_excerpt . '</p>';
  return $post_excerpt;
  }
```

You would then simply have `echo get_the_excerpt();` in your template files.

Comment: this may produce an invalid HTML, as you don't know what the excerpt contains, it might for example contain a div which from the spec is not allowed to be in a P

Comment: ^ post_excerpt, by default, cannot contain HTML. You'd have to modify the edit-post form to allow HTML. So it's pretty reasonable to assume the excerpt is plain text.

Answer (score 2):

the way to do this is by wrapping everything in a div with whatever class you want, like

```
<div class="myexcerpt">
<?php the_excerpt()?>
</div>
```

and then to style it (or JS) you can use

```
.myexcerpt p {}
```

`div` has no semantic value and this kind of things is exactly why it exist.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to avoid; overuse of divs...

Comment: there is no such thing as "overuse of divs"

Comment: There is definitely a lot of opinions on that subject but, `<div class="something"><p></p></div>` is not the same as `<p class="something"></p>` which I requested in the question.

Comment: so the answer is that you can't do what you want. without buffering the output and regex all Ps into that format